# How to save previous interaction using reactiveValues

Tags: shiny

I am developing a table which does some calculations each time that an action button is used. One column of my table depends on its previous value,

```
C_new <- C_old + B_new - A_new
```

For instance, if A=4, B=A+2 and C= C(-1) + B - A my expected results are

```
A   B  C
1   2  3
4   6  5
```

I have tried to save the previous value of column C using reactiveValue, as mentioned in  [How to “remember” information from the previous iteration when using reactiveTimer in Shiny?](http://How%20to%20%E2%80%9Cremember%E2%80%9D%20information%20from%20the%20previous%20iteration%20when%20using%20reactiveTimer%20in%20Shiny?),  but it doesn't work. I don't know where I am getting wrong.

Here is my code

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(textInput("c1","Example"),
           actionButton("update", "Update Table")),
  mainPanel(tableOutput("example"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  C_old <- reactive(x=3)

  values <- reactiveValues(df = data.frame(A=1, B=2, C=3)) 

  newEntry <- observeEvent(input$update,{

    A_new <- as.numeric(input$c1)
    B_new <- A_new + 2
    C_new <- isolate (C_old$x + B_new - A_new) 
    C_old$x <<- C_new

  new <- data.frame(A=A_new,B=B_new, C=C_new)

   # attach the new line to the old data frame here:
   values$df <- rbind(values$df, new)

  })

  # Print the content of values$df
  output$example <- renderTable({
   return(values$df)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Important to know, `observeEvent`s (similar to `observe`s) don't have outputs. You just observe a change and do something in their body, but nothing is supposed to be returned (this is different to `reactive({ })`, which also observes changes but has return values), useful [link](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html).

`Isolate` is not needed in `observeEvent` , because nothing triggers an update except for `input$update` (this is different to `observe` and `reactive`, where all changeable items in the body trigger an update).

Below is the solution to your problem. I used `reactiveVal` which stores one single updateable value (see `?reactiveVal` for help). After clicking the action button, I retrieve the old table by calling `values()`, calculate all new values (beware, I need to use `tail` to get only the last `C` value) and attach the result to the old value before storing the extended table into `values` by calling `values(new_df)`:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(numericInput("c1","Example", 0),
               actionButton("update", "Update Table")),
  mainPanel(tableOutput("example"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # stores the current data frame, called by values() and set by values(new_data_table)
  values <- reactiveVal(data.frame(A=1, B=2, C=3))

  # update values table on button click
  observeEvent(input$update,{

    old_values <- values()

    A_new <- input$c1
    B_new <- A_new + 2
    C_new <- tail(old_values$C, 1) + B_new - A_new  # tail to get the last C value

    new_values <- data.frame(A=A_new, B=B_new, C=C_new)

    # attach the new line to the old data frame here:
    new_df <- rbind(old_values, new_values)

    #store the result in values variable
    values(new_df)

  })

  # Print the content of values$df
  output$example <- renderTable({
    return(values())
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes you are right. I have changed my example following your suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Wow ! I didn't know about reactiveVal, thanks. I will see if I can implement this to my original table. For any chance, do you know what function I can use if I want C = C(-2) + B - A instead C= C(-1) + B - A? Last thing, could you please help me to increase my reputation? I can't vote if I do not have at least 15 point.

Comment: the last two values of C are `tail(C, 2)`, and the first entry of these is `head(..., 1)`, so the second-last one is `head(tail(C, 2), 1)`